# Unable to redirect the url in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wanna implement url encoding like http://www.host.abc/action?view=jobs in my spring web app but unable to get the job done through my strategy, which is

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);


    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);      
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home/action?view=jobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showJobs(Model model) {
        //some stuff goes here
        return ("/home/action?view=jobs");
    }       
}
```

home.jsp is

```
<c:if test="${param.view == 'jobs' }">
    <!-- List of Jobs -->
</c:if>
```

this give me warning

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jobsnetwork/home/action] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

and finally I added maping to WebApplicationInitializer class as

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext rootContext = 
                new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");

        context.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        XmlWebApplicationContext servletContext = 
                new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");

        // add the dispatcher servlet and map it to /
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = 
                context.addServlet("springDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(servletContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        dispatcher.addMapping("/home/action");// added mapping here

    }

}
```

the above stuff is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should contain the path only (`"/jobsnetwork/home/action"`), not the request parameters (`"?view=jobs"`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jobsnetwork/home/action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showJobs(@RequestParam("view") String view, Model model) {
    if (view.equals("jobs")) {
        // do stuff if ?view=jobs
    } else {
        // do stuff if not ?view=jobs
    }
}
```

Comment: still same warning and HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: I edited. Should be `@RequestMapping(value = "/home/action", `, not `@RequestMapping(value = "/home/action?view=jobs", `.

Comment: Man! still same warning and HTTP Status 404

Comment: I edited once again. See `@RequestMapping(value = "/jobsnetwork/home/action",`

Answer (score -1):

Just try to redirect:-

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);      
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showJobs(@RequestParam("view") String view,Model model) {
        //some stuff goes here
        return "redirect:/action?view=jobs";
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this makes server hanged up by repeatedly redirecting to that url ;-(